# Utilizar os valores do objeto anônimo dentro do construtor ao instanciar a classe em VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Olá, estou criando uma solução para gerar os arquivos do SPED Fiscal onde eu faço todas as regras de validação de cada classe logo na construção da mesma. Isso é necessário porque para cada Campo, Bloco ou Registro existem regras específicas. Consegui criar minhas classes para tipos que já fazem toda a validação mas estou tendo problemas em relação aos Registros, assim:

**Tipos personalizados de acordo com a documentação**

```
Namespace Tipos
    Public Class Caractere
        ...
    End Class
    Public Class Numerico(Of T)
        ...
    End Class
    Public Class Registro
        ...
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**Representação de 1 registro**

```
Imports Sped.Tipos
Namespace Tipos.Bloco0
    Public Class Registro0000
        Inherits Registro

        ' Propriedades da classe
        Public COD_VER As Numerico(Of Integer)
        Public COD_FIN As Numerico(Of Integer)
        Public DT_INI As Caractere
        Public DT_FIN As Caractere
        Public NOME As Caractere
        Public CNPJ As Caractere
        Public CPF As Caractere
        Public UF As Caractere
        Public IE As Caractere
        Public COD_MUN As Numerico(Of Integer)
        Public IM As Caractere
        Public SUFRAMA As Caractere
        Public IND_PERFIL As Caractere
        Public IND_ATIV As Numerico(Of Integer)

        ' Construtor (aqui está o problema)
        Public Sub New()
            ... validação das regras do registro ...
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Preciso passar as propriedades à classe e validar na iniciação dela, sendo assim eu entendo que usaria [isso](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/object-initializers-named-and-anonymous-types) ficando assim:

**Inicialização do registro dentro do bloco 0**

```
Imports Sped.Tipos.Registros.Bloco0
Namespace Tipos.Blocos
    Public Class Bloco0

        Public registro0000 as Registro0000
        ... outros registros aqui

        Public Sub New()
            registro0000 = New Registro0000 With {
                .COD_VER = 1,
                .COD_FIN = 1, 
                .DT_INI = "20000101",
                .DT_FIN = "20200101"
                .NOME = "Foo"
                .CNPJ = "00000000000000"
                .CPF = ""
                .UF = "MG"
                .IE = ""
                .COD_MUN = 0000000
                .IM = ""
                .SUFRAMA = ""
                .IND_PERFIL = 1
                .IND_ATIV = 1
            }
            ... outras inicializações aqui
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Em resumo, preciso conseguir utilizar os parâmetros que estou passando usando uma inicialização com um objeto anônimo dentro do construtor do meu registro para então validar esses valores mas, não estou conseguindo entender como processar isso e, até então o `With {}` só ocorre após a inicialização... Como resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Oi

Inicializas o objecto no constructor

```
Imports Sped.Tipos
Namespace Tipos.Bloco0
    Public Class Registro0000
        Inherits Registro

        ' Propriedades da classe
        Public Property COD_VER As Numerico(Of Integer)
        Public Property COD_FIN As Numerico(Of Integer)
        Public Property DT_INI As Caractere
        Public Property DT_FIN As Caractere
        Public Property NOME As Caractere
        Public Property CNPJ As Caractere
        Public Property CPF As Caractere
        Public Property UF As Caractere
        Public Property IE As Caractere
        Public Property COD_MUN As Numerico(Of Integer)
        Public Property IM As Caractere
        Public Property SUFRAMA As Caractere
        Public Property IND_PERFIL As Caractere
        Public Property IND_ATIV As Numerico(Of Integer)

        ' Construtor (aqui está o problema)
        Public Sub New( COD_VER As Numerico(Of Integer), COD_FIN As Numerico(Of Integer), DT_INI As Caractere, DT_FIN As Caractere, NOME As Caractere, CNPJ As Caractere, CPF As Caractere, UF As Caractere, IE As Caractere, COD_MUN As Numerico(Of Integer), IM As Caractere, SUFRAMA As Caractere, IND_PERFIL As Caractere, IND_ATIV As Numerico(Of Integer))

        Me.COD_VER = COD_VER 
        Me.COD_FIN = COD_FIN 
        Me.DT_INI = DT_INI 
        Me.DT_FIN = DT_FIN 
        Me.NOME = NOME 
        Me.CNPJ = CNPJ 
        Me.CPF = CPF 
        Me.UF = UF 
        Me.IE = IE 
        Me.COD_MUN = COD_MUN 
        Me.IM = IM 
        Me.SUFRAMA = SUFRAMA 
        Me.IND_PERFIL = IND_PERFIL 
        Me.IND_ATIV = IND_ATIV 


            ... validação das regras do registro ...
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace



Imports Sped.Tipos.Registros.Bloco0
Namespace Tipos.Blocos
    Public Class Bloco0

        Public registro0000 as Registro0000
        ... outros registros aqui

        Public Sub New()
            registro0000 = New Registro0000(, 1,, 1, , "20000101",, "20200101", "Foo", "00000000000000", "", "MG", "", 0000000, "", "", 1, 1
            )
            ... outras inicializações aqui
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```